package slices is not in GOROOT
I run prometheus
make test

https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus
But get an error. What am I doing wrong?
 package slices is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go-1.18/src/slices)


The error message indicates you have / are using Go 1.18.
But the slices package was added in Go 1.21. Either upgrade your go installation, or don't use the slices package.
On a side note, only the 2 most recent major Go releases are supported (patched) officially (currently Go 1.23 and 1.22), so you shouldn't be using older Go versions anyway.

It also happens on Arch Linux when you have gcc-go package installed instead of go (same message, except that it looks for the library in /usr/src/slices instead).
In that case, the solution is to replace gcc-go with the stock go.
